# Button flickering

Tags: html, css

Whenever i hover near the left/right/top side of the arrow in flickers really fast. It acts normally when i hover exactly at the center of it. What could be the problem?
Also, when i refresh the page, the arrow should not be visible while we are looking at the top of the screen, but it is visible. Do i need to add some other lines for it not to appear after a refresh?
https://jsfiddle.net/gvsz38h6/7/

```
<style>
 .myBtn:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 animation: animate 1.5s infinite;
 }
 @keyframes animate {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(-20px, -20px);
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(20px, 20px);
            }
</style>
<body>
 <script>
    var mybutton = document.getElementById('myBtn');
            window.onscroll = function () {
                scrollFunction();
            };

            function scrollFunction() {
                if (
                    document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20
                ) {
                    mybutton.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    mybutton.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            function topFunction() {
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
                document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            }
  </script>
  <div id="myBtn" class="myBtn" onclick="topFunction()" style="mybutton" title="Top of the webpage"></div>
<div class="space50";
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over it, it moves.

When you over over the edge of it, it moves out from under the mouse pointer so it isn't hovered any more. So it moves back under the mouse pointer. So it is hovered again and it moves away again. Etc.

Don't move the hover target itself. Wrap something with a static position around the element you want to move and make the static element the hover target.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're moving the actual element that is triggering the animation. Effectively, on hover the element moves, but stops moving because it's no longer hovered, but gains hover and starts moving... Considering reworking your code so the visible and animated portion is a pseudo `::after` element. Additionally, you are moving your actual "clickable" element so when someone does hover over it, they cannot click it.